# How to holster your weapon in Fallout 3?

Tags: pc, fallout-3

I just noticed (during a loading screen) that is possible to holster your weapon.

I've checked the keys in the option, yet i was unable find anything related. So how do you holster your weapon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hold down whatever key you have Reload bound to ('**R**' by default)for about 2 seconds. For melee weapons, you can just tap the button, since they have no ammunition.